# 2019 Macbook Pro boots straight to internet recovery

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, internet-recovery

I have a 2019 Macbook pro that had a swollen battery.  The battery was causing the laptop to crash randomly, but I could boot into it only if I fully drained the battery first, after which it would list about 5 mins in the OS before crashing.

After replacing the battery I tried to reinstall the OS with no success.  I followed a guide to boot into DFU mode and restore it, which cleared out my SSD (which was fine), but now I can't find a way to install macOS on it again.

Currently, with no installed version of macOS, it boots to the folder with a question mark on it (expected).  Anything I try seems to bring me to internet recovery, which at first succeeds (countdown timer), but then just hangs when the Apple and progress bar is shown.

Things I've tried:

- Reset SMC
- Reset NVRAM
- Internet Recovery (it completes the countdown timer, but when it shows the apple and progress bar, no progress is ever made)
- MacOS install media (properly created and is detected with option boot, but when selected on boot, it goes straight to internet recovery which fails as described above)
- I've tried using an Ethernet cable through a usb-c dongle

I haven't tried setting DNS at my router to Google's DNS (saw this on the linked post below).

I saw this comment in another question that suggests taking it to the Apple store if "nothing else works" https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/423553/459225

Has anyone else run into this?  Are there any other things I can try?  Also, what are Apple Geniuses able to do at the Mac Store that's different from the known boot commands and keyboard combinations we have available to us?

The laptop produces a clean diagnostic report running the apple diagnostic tool.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Apple Store staff have Service software that is superior to Apple Configurator, and other diagnostic tools not available to users. If you're lucky, you can get an appointment quickly, and they'll identify the problem in minutes, and fix it there if possible. It may be that the old battery has damaged the on-board storage somehow. Who replaced the battery? Did the volume ever boot up after the replacement?